# Is this rhythm called a salsa or samba or something else?

Tags: rhythm

Is there a name for this little beat?

```
         main: .--.|--.-|--.-|-.--
accompaniment: .-.-|.-.-|.-.-|.-.-
```

(a dot is a hit and a dash is a rest)

Sorry for the makeshift notation and lack of terms, I'm not doing a great job at conveying this question... I hope my message gets through...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you wrote down is the clave of a ryhthm called [Bossa Nova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bossa_nova), although you usually write it as two bar pattern. It's a Brasilian rhyhthm pretty close to samba, mostly slower.

Comment: Bah, ignore my previous comments, I see that Wikipedia has the beat there in a little image.  +1!

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for but couldn't remember.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean a son clave ? usally it is  something  with  3 against 2 or  2-against 3 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Son_and_rumba_clave.png

or

X . . X . . X . . . X . X . . .

Answer (score 0):

This is a very typical bossa nova 'clave'. 
XooX ooXo ooXo oXoo
It comes up in samba sometimes too, depending on the batucada—some schools play this rhythm in accents in their caixas.